# How to add tree view title to added button icon in odoo?

Tags: odoo-11

I have created confirm button in tree view. How to add the tree view title to this column? This is my code

```xml
<record id="view_employee_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.tree</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Employees">
            <button name="confirm" string="Confirm" class="oe_highlight"/>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="work_phone"/>
            <field name="work_email"/>
            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
            <field name="department_id"/>
            <field name="job_id"/>
            <field name="parent_id"/>
            <field name="coach_id" invisible="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>      
</record>
```

Comment: First : you should add type to button object or action .
Second : Inherit view in custom addon then add your new columns or new buttons .
Third : what do you mean : How to add the tree view title to this column?

Comment: Omar Thanks for your reply... I can view the button... I need to add the header for that button column.. How to do it?

Comment: @ssss I don't think that it is possible to add a header. How about adding a `title` attribute on the button?

Comment: @adekock11 Have tried it with title..But didn't work..